# How do I sync up the new version of SQLite with Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

When I started Visual Studio today, I got a message that there was an update. It turned out to be SQLite, and I updated it.

Now, though, I can't compile my app, because I get the msg, "*Could not find SDK "SQLite.WinRT, Version=3.7.14.1".*"

-and the Warning:

*The referenced component 'SQLite for Windows Runtime' could not be found.*

The SQLite for Windows Runtime Reference is now "decorated" with a yellow yield sign (icon/glyph). So what need I do - that claims to be version 3.7.14.1, so I don't know who or what is looking for a different version of SQLite... ?

Comment: Removing the old reference and re-adding it should do the trick.

Comment: If you make it an official answer, I'll check it as such.

Comment: I can't figure out how to remove the old reference - I unchecked it in the 'add reference' area and checked the newer reference but I still get the error.

Comment: @Yosem: You have to expand the References, select the one you want to "refresh," right-click and select "Remove", then add it back via References | r-click | Add Reference.

Comment: Thanks Clay, I found it - they have hidden that reference pretty well. I had to click view all files and then search for the offending reference to the older version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing the old reference and re-adding it should do the trick.